# Windows phone 8 apps -- Facebook integration

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to integrate My Windows Phone 8 app with Facebook and I am using

ShareLinkTask class. like below

```
ShareLinkTask shareLinkTask = new ShareLinkTask();
shareLinkTask.Title ="title";
shareLinkTask.LinkUri = new Uri(Image URL, UriKind.Absolute);
shareLinkTask.Message ="text message";
shareLinkTask.Show();
```

The problem is: I am able to share the particular image successfully in Facebook and when we click the image it should redirect to a particular site only but it is redirecting to image URL only.

How can we pass the Image URL and Site URL to Facebook using ShareLinkTask or is there any other way to find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect on site url then set

`shareLinkTask.LinkUri = new Uri(Site URL, UriKind.Absolute);`

and use site thumbnail Image to visible on facebook post.

Facebook redirect to same source from where post is coming either image url or site.

Comment: Here i just want to sent image url as well as site url (both must). for that i seen the example. we can build the url like this..

Comment: shareLinkTask.LinkUri = new Uri("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=" + 196115880540866 + "&link=" +"http://www.sheikhmohammed.co.ae/vgn-ext-templating/v/index.jsp?vgnextoid=293ffd02ec2cd210VgnVCM1000004d64a8c0RCRD&appInstanceName=default" + "&picture=" + uri+"&name=Facebook%20Dialogs&caption=Reference%20Documentation&%20description=Using%20Dialogs%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&message=Facebook%20Dialogs%20are%20so%20easy!&%20redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response", UriKind.Absolute);

Comment: ..in this above url we are passing both image url and site url. but it is not working. it is posting sucessfully to the facebook. but there not binding image and site urls.  please suggest us.. :(